# sort data.frame by character name

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` like this:

```
DeviceName                SessionLength
samsung SM-A500FU         6168
samsung SM-N9005          16199
iPad3,3                   5447
Sony C6602                13838
Iriver tolino tab 7       13657
iPhone6,2                 13434
samsung SAMSUNG-SGH-I317  13292
...
```

I need to sort this table to see `DeviceName` that have all `SessionLengths < 200`. Any ideas?

Comment: `subset(df, SessionLength < 200)`. Though you should post what you have tried when asking a question.

Comment: Or `df[df$SessionLength < 200, ]`.

Comment: If you want to sort the data, you can use `df[order(df$SessionLength),]`

Comment: not what i'm looking for. For example I have four SessionLengths (150, 300, 456, 500) for Sony C6602. The key word is ALL SessionLengths must be less then 200. So this Sony C6602 must not in my out. But device iPad3,3 with SessionLengths(120,50,189,100) must be in my Out. SO, in my out I have only DeviceName list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `aggregate()` function combined with `max()` to identify the largest value of `SessionLength` for each `DeviceName` and store the result in a new data frame `df2`:

```
df2 <- aggregate(SessionLength ~ . , df1, max)
```

Then we can take a subset of this data frame, selecting only those devices with a value of `SessionLength` below a certain limit. Here I have set the limit to 10000, since with the sample data given in the OP a limit of 200 would result in an empty vector:

```
> as.vector(with(df2, DeviceName[SessionLength < 10000]))
#[1] "iPad3,3"           "samsung SM-A500FU"
```

The result contains only the device names for which all entries of the `SessionLength` value are smaller than 10000.

**data**

```
df1 <-read.table(text=" DeviceName                SessionLength
                       'samsung SM-A500FU'         6168
                       'samsung SM-N9005'          16199
                       'iPad3,3'                   5447
                       'iPad3,3'                   2345
                       'Sony C6602'                13838
                       'Iriver tolino tab 7'       13657
                       'iPhone6,2'                 13434
                       'samsung SAMSUNG-SGH-I317'  13292", header=T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the subset and order functions.

```
# Data Frame
my.df <- data.frame( name = c( "D", "E", "Z", "A", "R", "U", "B", "X" )
                   , qty  = c( 100, 300, 500, 200, 30, 10, 40, 50 ) 
                   )

# Subset
my.200 <- subset( x      = my.df 
                , subset = qty < 200
                )

  name qty
1    D 100
5    R  30
6    U  10
7    B  40
8    X  50

# Ordering
my.order <- order( x = my.200$name )

[1] 4 1 2 3 5    

# Ordered Data Frame
my.200   <- my.200[ my.order, ]

  name qty
7    B  40
1    D 100
5    R  30
6    U  10
8    X  50
```